# Kant's argument for experience of outer things

Tags: kant

Have I got this right?

1. I have empirical consciousness of my existence
2. a determination such as this presupposes ‘something permanent in perception’
3. All that I inwardly intuit is my series of representations, which cannot offer this something permanent
4. Therefore this something permanent must be provided by something outer, and empirical consciousness of my existence is at once experience of something outer

Thanks!

Comment: Looks pretty good, can you unpack what you mean by "empirical consciousness"? That's probably the only place where there's room for a big error in what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly Kant's argument. It can be reformulated as follows, in order to make it perhaps a little bit more clear:

1. I am conscious of objects of my inner sense.
2. Perception of objects in time involves them being articulated into substances and their states (this is the conclusion of the *First Analogy of Experience*).
3. What I intuit through inner sense isn't articulated into substances and their states.
4. **Therefore:** I must be aware of objects articulated into substances and their states through another means, through the outer sense.

The first premise is not only quite obvious, but also presupposed by Berkeley etc. whose arguments Kant aims at disarming. The second premise is the conclusion of the *First Analogy of Experience*. The third premise is quite substantive because it says that our inner awareness has a certain 'degenerate' form which makes impossible to perceive objects of inner sense as enduring substances.